# Why does Liquibase want to dropPrimaryKey and addPrimaryKey?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I have Postgres databases generated with Eclipse Link. Between these databases is not any change, but when I run liquibase for generating diffChangeLog, it generates changesets with dropPrimaryKey and addPrimaryKey. I don't understand why it generates these records for all primary keys of all tables. Names, order of columns are the same for both tables.

Example of changeset

```
<changeSet author="michal2 (generated)" id="1436872322297-8">
        <dropPrimaryKey tableName="country_translation"/>
        <addPrimaryKey columnNames="country_id, translations_id" constraintName="country_translation_pkey" tableName="country_translation"/>
    </changeSet>
```

Sql of original table

```
CREATE TABLE country_translation
(
  country_id bigint NOT NULL,
  translations_id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT country_translation_pkey PRIMARY KEY (country_id, translations_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_country_translation_country_id FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
      REFERENCES country (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_country_translation_translations_id FOREIGN KEY (translations_id)
      REFERENCES translation (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE country_translation
  OWNER TO hotels;
```

Sql of reference table

```
CREATE TABLE country_translation
(
  country_id bigint NOT NULL,
  translations_id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT country_translation_pkey PRIMARY KEY (country_id, translations_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_country_translation_country_id FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
      REFERENCES country (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_country_translation_translations_id FOREIGN KEY (translations_id)
      REFERENCES translation (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE country_translation
  OWNER TO hotels;
```

Liquibase command with arguments

```
./liquibase \
      --driver=org.postgresql.Driver \
      --classpath=/home/michal2/tools/postgresql-jdbc-driver/postgresql-jdbc.jar \
      --changeLogFile=changelog-hotels.xml \
      --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/hotels" \
      --username=hotels \
      --password=hotels \
      --defaultSchemaName=public \
    --logLevel=info \
    diffChangeLog \
    --referenceUrl="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/hotels_liquibase" \
    --referenceUsername=hotels \
    --referencePassword=hotels \
        --referenceDefaultSchemaName=public
```

I'm using version 3.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed for Liquibase 3.4.1 https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2416